# D3: Detect mouse wheel event through overlaid SVG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

In the following example, is there a way to for the `zoomArea` to detect a mouse wheel event that happens while pointing on one of the grey circles? The aim is to not interrupt the zoom behaviour when doing so. The circles should still be able to receive pointer events in order to e.g. display tooltips.

```js
var dataset = [0, 2345786000, 10000000000];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
var w = 500, h = 200;
var padding = 50;
svg.attr("width", w)
   .attr("height", h);

// Background pattern 
var patternSize = 5;
svg.append("defs")
            .append("pattern")
            .attr("id", "dotPattern")
            .attr("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
            .attr("width", patternSize)
            .attr("height", patternSize)
            .append("circle")
            .attr("cx", patternSize / 2)
            .attr("cy", patternSize / 2)
            .attr("r", 2)
            .style("stroke", "none")
            .style("fill", "lightgrey")
            .style("opacity", 0.5);
   
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([0, 10000000000])
    .range([padding, w-padding]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .ticks(5);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class","axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h-padding) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
    
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .on("zoom", build)
            .scaleExtent([1, 20]);           
zoom.x(xScale);

var clipPath = svg.append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", padding)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width",w-2*padding)
        .attr("height", h-padding);
var zoomArea = svg.append("g")
         .attr("class", "zoomArea")
         .style("cursor","move")
         .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
var zoomRect = zoomArea.append("rect")
     .attr("x", padding)
     .attr("y", 0)
     .attr("width", w-2*padding)
     .attr("height", h-padding)
     .style("fill", "url(#dotPattern)")
     .style("pointer-events", "all")
     .style("cursor","move")
     .call(zoom);

zoomArea.selectAll("circles")          
 .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d){
   return xScale(d);
  })
  .attr("cy", h/2)
  .attr("r",10)
  .attr("fill","grey")

function build(){
     svg.select("g.axis").call(xAxis);
          d3.selectAll("circle")
             .attr("cx", function(d){
         return xScale(d);
        });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "allowing the zoom to work"? Do you want the grey circles to zoom in and enlarge?

Comment: No, I want to have the same zoom behaviour across the visible canvas. Thanks for pointing this out, will amend the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call zoom on circles as well.

```
zoomArea.selectAll("circles")          
    .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d){
    return xScale(d);
  })
  .attr("cy", h/2)
  .attr("r",10)
  .attr("fill","grey")
  .call(zoom);//call zoom on circle
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pVIlphQw2EwirCWueKRe?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well that was easy! Brilliant :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing the same:

First make a rectangle with the fill background,don't attach the zoom listener to it.

```
var zoomRect = zoomArea.append("rect")
     .attr("x", padding)
     .attr("y", 0)
     .attr("width", w-2*padding)
     .attr("height", h-padding)
     .style("fill", "url(#dotPattern)")
     .style("cursor","move");//no zoom call
```

Not attach circles.

```
zoomArea.selectAll("circles")          
    .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d){
    return xScale(d);
  })
  .attr("cy", h/2)
  .attr("r",10)
  .attr("fill","grey");
```

Now make another rectangle same as the first except it has zoom behavior and `fill transparent`..so that its above all elements to handle the zoom behavior.

```
zoomArea.append("rect")
     .attr("x", padding)
     .attr("y", 0)
     .attr("width", w-2*padding)
     .attr("height", h-padding)
     .style("fill", "transparent")
     .style("pointer-events", "all")
     .style("cursor","move")
     .call(zoom);
```

Working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Jf57bt76CXbrLIiCevj1?p=preview)

Hope this helps too!

Comment: This does not work in my actual code since the circles need to receive pointer events for tooltips. I didn't think of mentioning that in my question, sorry for that--it's a great answer none the less and might help someone else, upvoted.